# Combining multiple lists to a data frame R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-manipulation

The following is only a small MWE of my whole data. Assume I have a list containing two matrices of the following format

```
dat1 <- matrix(rnorm(3*5), nrow = 5, ncol =3)
colnames(dat1) <- c("power_FX", "power_MX_LLSM" ,"power_MX_LCD")
rownames(dat1) <- c("nu=1", "nu=3", "nu=5", "nu=10", "nu=30")

dat2 <- matrix(rnorm(3*5), nrow = 5, ncol =3)
colnames(dat2) <- c("power_FX", "power_MX_LLSM" ,"power_MX_LCD")
rownames(dat2) <- c("nu=1", "nu=3", "nu=5", "nu=10", "nu=30")

list.dat <- list(n600 = dat1, n700 = dat2)
```

I want to combine those two matrices in the list into one data frame with 4 columns: one for the list name, one for the row names of the matrix, one for the column names of the matrix and one containing the numerical values:

```
n    nu  type      value
600  1   power_FX  ...
600  1   power_MX_LLSM ...
.    .   ...    ...
600  3   power_FX  ...
600  3   power_MX_LLSM ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the transformation for each list element in `lapply()` and then bind everything together with `do.call("rbind", ...)`. Most of the transformation is done by `reshape2::melt()` which has a method for matrices, which does most of what you want.

```r
df <- do.call("rbind", 
              lapply(seq_along(list.dat), function(l) {
                tmp <- cbind(n = names(list.dat[l]), reshape2::melt(list.dat[[l]], varnames = c("nu", "type")))
                tmp$n <- as.numeric(gsub("n", "", tmp$n))
                tmp$nu <- as.numeric(gsub("nu=", "", tmp$nu))
                tmp
              })
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way using `tidyverse` -

```
library(tidyverse)

list.dat %>%
  map_df(~.x %>% as.data.frame %>% rownames_to_column('nu'), .id = 'n') %>%
  mutate(across(c(n, nu), parse_number)) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('power'), names_to = 'type')

#      n    nu  type            value
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
# 1   600     1 power_FX      -0.524 
# 2   600     1 power_MX_LLSM  0.102 
# 3   600     1 power_MX_LCD   1.41  
# 4   600     3 power_FX       0.494 
# 5   600     3 power_MX_LLSM  0.492 
# 6   600     3 power_MX_LCD  -0.383 
# 7   600     5 power_FX      -0.334 
# 8   600     5 power_MX_LLSM -0.558 
# 9   600     5 power_MX_LCD   0.474 
#10   600    10 power_FX      -0.0823
# … with 20 more rows
```